# Problems with fetching data from http in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to fetch data in iOS 9 like this:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *avaliableVersion = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://energyapp.co/fonts/vers.php"] options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:avaliableVersion encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(str);
```

As a result, it loads very long time, but here is just few symbols. And result in "str" is empty.

Comment: I suspect that the crash isn't occurring in these two lines, but have you disabled ATS?

Comment: Paulw11, yes i have disabled ATS.

Comment: Check that `error` isn't nil and log it if it isn't

Comment: The problem is not with your iOS code at all. Pasting `http://energyapp.co/fonts/vers.php` into a browser (I'm using Chrome) takes forever to load. The problem is on the PHP side. ![](https://www.evernote.com/l/AEYO8fS36WJLjpjLliMyNTy6_ZQZONCEk7Q)